# Problem to paralel tv digital reciever

Tags: antenna, receiver

Here is my C-Band parabolic tv digital receiver. As shown by the pictures, the incoming coax cable (INPUT) connected both the outer and the core. One goes to digital receiver 1 (receiver 1), and another goes to digital receiver 2 (receiver 2).

- If BOTH receivers are turned ON, they are working fine.
- If receiver 1 is turned OFF, receiver 2 is working fine.
- But, if receiver 2 is turned OFF, the receiver 1 is NOT working.

They are supposed to be connected by a spliter. Unfortunately, I don't have a suitable one. This is temporary until I get it. Then my question is, why is the receiver 1 can not be independent from digital receiver 2 (but not vice versa)? Which one is better in term of loss affected by the connection compared to if compared to use combiner?

[image: Co-axial's connection]
[image: Digital receiver 1]
[image: Digital receiver 2]

Comment: Is receiver 1 plugged into the back of receiver 2 for power?

Comment: No, it is not. You can see the cabling. They are separated as it is using spliter.

Comment: I was asking about the power cord.  Some boxes like that have a switched outlet on the back, without it being marked as switched.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP manually twists together coax cores and mantles, knowing that only a splitter can properly fulfill the role of splitting signals, and hopes to get an explanation why things behave erratically and unpredictably: Obviously, erratically and unpredictably just twisting cores and mantles together leads to erratic and unpredictable results. There's nothing to be answered here!

Comment: What does "Not working" mean?

Comment: @Duston, "not working" on the tv screen is shown "no signal". Mean, there is no input signal from the digital receiver to the television because there is no input signal to the digital receiver 1.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, if "OP manually twists together coax cores and mantles, knowing that only a splitter can properly fulfill the role of splitting" the case, why does the digital receiver 2 is working fine without any effect of digital receiver 1? If both having the same problem, your opinion could be true. Is in it quite strange?

Comment: What happens if you disconnect Receiver 2?  One idea is that Receiver 2 is sending a signal (either DC or data) out to the LNB.  Another idea is that Receiver 2's front end when off is effectively shunting the end of the coax (static protection maybe?)

Comment: No effect. I have swapped the receiver, Receiver1 connected to the cable 2,<-->Receiver2 connected to the cable 1, also problem.

Comment: @ZeissIkon, I am not sure that I am fully understand your question ("_Is receiver 1 plugged into the back of receiver 2 for power_"). But both the tv and receiver are located in a different palace. Receiver 1 is in living room and the receiver 2 is in kitchen. So, they are totally separated.

Comment: @Sitorus no, that's the whole point: it's not quite strange.